# JSON file created using Pandas is bigger than the original Excel file

Tags: python, json, pandas

I wanted to convert my Excel data to JSON as JSON is very light in weight.

I tried with a simple Excel file, and its size is 8KB, but my converted JSON file size is 17KB. Why is the JSON file bigger? I assumed it would be smaller.

I tried with:

```
df=pd.read_excel("path/myfile.xlsx")
df.to_json("path/myfile.json")
```

Comment: Without seeing your data, we can only speculate. `xlsx` is gzip-compressed by definition so this is really apples vs oranges anyway.

Comment: "JSON is very light in weight". Well JSON is plain text (at least the way you are saving it, without compression), which is not really good at reducing space.

Comment: Can you please try with converting a simple excel file to Json using Pandas and see the size..?